# URL request of 20 most recent blog posts (Java)

Tags: java, android, api, http

I want to request a list of the 20 most recent blog posts from any particular blog. For this example I want to request it from http://bleacherreport.com/los-angeles-lakers

In my code I have

```
    URL blogFeedUrl = new URL();
```

How do I call the URL correctly that I listed above? I've tried googling for Bleacher Reports API or documentation for developers but nothing comes up. I'm writing this in JAVA by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is very general, but I'll give you an answer based on the criteria you provided. The website http://bleacherreport.com/los-angeles-lakers provides an RSS feed, which you will use to fetch the most recent articles.

For information on RSS, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

For a tutorial on how to read and parse RSS for Java/Android, see here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RSSFeed/article.html

Comment: I actually did see that tutorial. I was wondering if there was another way to do it besides how he showed.